# Complex equation solutions

Tags: complex-analysis

In complex analysis how can I find all solutions of the following equation,

$$\sin(z) = \sin(\overline z)?$$

I see that this is true if $z=\overline{z}$
So I asked myself where that is true , I think its when $z$ is only real.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sin(x+iy)=\sin(x)\cosh(y)+i\cos(x)\sinh(y)\\
\sin(x-iy)=\sin(x)\cosh(y)-i\cos(x)\sinh(y)$$
This equality leads us to $\cos(x)\sinh(y)=0$. 
Then $y=0$ and/or $x=k\pi+{\pi\over2}$. The real answers are only one branch of reply.

Comment: This is completely unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

No, there are more solutions besides real line.

Recall that $2i \sin(z)=e^{iz}-e^{-iz}$, then by letting $z=x+iy$, we have that 
$$\begin{align}
2i\sin(x+iy)&=e^{i(x+iy)}-e^{-i(x+iy)}=e^{-y}(\cos(x)+i\sin(x))-e^{y}(\cos(x)-i\sin(x))\\
&=-\left(e^{y}-e^{-y}\right)\cos(x)+i\left(e^y+e^{-y}\right)\sin(x).
\end{align}$$
Hence $\sin(x+iy)=\sin(x-iy)$ if and only if
$$-\left(e^{y}-e^{-y}\right)\cos(x)+i\left(e^y+e^{-y}\right)\sin(x)=\left(e^{y}-e^{-y}\right)\cos(x)+i\left(e^y+e^{-y}\right)\sin(x)$$
that is
$$\left(e^{y}-e^{-y}\right)\cos(x)=0.$$
Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

The standard addition formulas for sine and cosine also hold in the complex plane, because of the identity principle of analytic functions.

Hence, from $\sin z-\sin\bar{z}=0$, we get the equivalent equation
$$
2\sin\frac{z-\bar{z}}{2}\cos\frac{z+\bar{z}}{2}=0
$$

The zeros of the complex sine and cosine are on the real line, as you can show from the definition:
$$
\sin w=0
\quad\text{if and only if}\quad
e^{iw}=e^{-iw}
\quad\text{if and only if}\quad
e^{2iw}=1
$$
and, similarly,
$$
\cos w=0
\quad\text{if and only if}\quad
e^{2iw}=-1
$$
Hence you get
$$
z-\bar{z}=2k\pi
\quad\text{or}\quad
z+\bar{z}=\pi+2k\pi
$$
for $k$ an integer. Can you finish?